# Converting a text input to a number input

Tags: html, text, input, tags, numbers

Currently I have a bunch text inputs, which I can't change the HTML for (as it is pre-generated), but I want to convert them from type="text" to type="number", is there a bit of jQuery or JavaScript I can use to achieve this?

This is in a small application for mobile devices.

Basically I want to convert

```
<input type="text" id="MyID" name="MyName">
```

to

```
<input type="number" id="MyID" name="MyName">
```

I was trying something like

```
<script>
  function DoWhenReady() {
    $('#MyID').attr('type', 'number');
  }
  $(document).ready(DoWhenReady);
</script>
```

In the header, but without success - suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `$('#MyID').prop('type', 'number');` (jQuery 1.6+ required for [`prop`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/))

Comment: perfect - would have accepted it already but I have to wait 5 minutes :-(